# In place of cream of tartar to stabilize egg whites?

Tags: egg-whites

https://sallysbakingaddiction.com/sky-high-chocolate-mousse-pie/#tasty-recipes-69503

Using this recipe, calls for cream of tartar. I don't have that, I've only got tartaric acid. Would that work? Or anything else in substitute?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tartaric acid is the scientific name for cream of tartar. (Edit: not true - that's potassium bitartrate - but should work fine regardless.)

Comment: What  would happen if I didn't add it to the egg whites? Would it ruin the texture of the mousse or something?

Comment: Cream of tartar helps stabilize a meringue, but isn't crucial. Particularly in a recipe like that I doubt you'd see much difference.

Answer (score 5):

Your acid will work in place of potassium bitartrate, AKA cream of tartar.
Lemon juice, vinegar, or even baking powder will also work.
Six good substitutes: https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/cream-of-tartar-substitutes
Most common baking powders are a mix of sodium bicarbonate and cream of tartar. As per link, add 1.5 tsp baking powder in place of 1 tsp cream of tartar.

Answer (score -1):

Take some raw fish and toss it in a blender with half-and-half. Voilà! Cream of tartare.

Comment: hahahha made me laugh!